# Searching obsolute occurrence of a string in a file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I need to find obsolute occurrence of a string in a file.

- If a string "I_LOVE_INDIA" in a file.
- If the input string is "I_LOVE" then search status should be false.
- If the input string is "I_LOVE_INDIA" then search status should be true.

I am not able to get using below one:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\asdf\def.txt").IndexOf("string_to_search")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\asdf\def.txt").IndexOf("I_LOVE_INDIA")
```

If you want it to fail when you look for  "I_LOVE_INDIA_TOO" then you'll need to check for that, eg:

```
Dim s as String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\asdf\def.txt")
Dim success as Boolean = CheckStringContainsILoveIndia(s)

Public Function CheckStringContainsILoveIndia(Byval s as String) as Boolean
Dim success as Boolean = False
If s.IndexOf("I_LOVE_INDIA_TOO") == -1 AND s.IndexOf("I_LOVE_INDIA") > -1 Then
success = True    
End If
return success
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thompson Thanks for input. But if i take below case,then its not working
s.IndexOf("I_LOVE_INDIA_TOO") == -1 AND s.IndexOf("I_LOVE") > -1 Then also its returning true, but at that case its should return false. What i really require is i want  to found obsolute string, not half string. If part of string is there, the out put should be false.

Comment: Hi thompson .. please help me out in this issue.